# How to write shell script for docker system prune as schedule

Tags: linux, bash, docker, cron

**docker system prune** wants answer y/n. How to i pass in shell script
my shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
docker stop registry
docker system prune
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v /etc/docker/registry/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml registry:2
```

I'm configured cron expression as every minutes

**crontab -e**

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/sansli/dc.sh
```

How do i test?
I'm checking the created dated as docker ps -a

Comment: `docker system prune -f`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is `docker system prune -f`, which will remove all stopped containers, all unused networks, all dangling images and build caches.

You can use crontab to periodic running this command. Look at this example of crontab:

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/docker system prune -f
```

You can also put this command into your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
docker stop registry
docker system prune -f
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v /etc/docker/registry/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml registry:2
```

Comment: @Sansli, nice to hear! Please have a look here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)